# Changing check boxes combination based on radio button selected value?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a system in which student will have to select his class via radio buttons. And then I want to display course offered for that class via check boxes so he can check subjects.Or in simple word I want to display different check boxes for different radio button selected value.Help needed for this?

```
BCA
<input type="radio" name="Course_BCA" value="BCA">
B.Com
<input type="radio" name="Course_BCA" value="B.Com">
B.Sc
<input type="radio" name="Course_BCA" value="B.Sc">
B.A
<input type="radio" name="Course_BCA" value="B.A">
```

Here should be checkboxes,If BCA is selected by user then

```
<input type="checkbox" name="eng" value="English">
<input type="checkbox" name="math" value="math">
```

would be diplayed.and if he selects B.Com then

```
<input type="checkbox" name="stat" value="stat">
<input type="checkbox" name="comp" value="comp">
```

should displayed to him.And same is case for rest to two.How I will do this?

Comment: Care to show some of the code you tried?

Comment: do you mind posting your codes too ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc(myid)
{

    value=document.getElementById(myid).value;


    if(value=='BCA')
    {document.getElementById("eng").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("math").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("stat").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("comp").disabled=true;
    }
    else if(value=='B.Com')
    {
        document.getElementById("eng").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("math").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("stat").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("comp").disabled=false;
    }

}
</script>

BCA
<input type="radio" name="Course_BCA" id="BCA" value="BCA" onChange="fnc(this.id)">
B.Com
<input type="radio" name="Course_BCA" id="B.Com" value="B.Com" onChange="fnc(this.id)">
B.Sc
<input type="radio" name="Course_BCA"  id="B.Sc" value="B.Sc">
B.A
<input type="radio" name="Course_BCA"  id="B.A" value="B.A">

<input type="checkbox" name="eng" id="eng" value="English" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" name="math" id="math" value="math" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" name="stat" id="stat" value="stat" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" name="comp" id="comp" value="comp" disabled>
```

I hope it'll be helpful for you

Comment: That's not what i need. You have not understood problem.I have 4 radio buttons of classes.And when student select Inter,courses offered in Inter should be displayed in check boxes,So he can make choice of his courses.

Comment: @NaeemShakir you don't expect me to post full code do you? Its just the concept. If you want though, then why don't you post your code in the right manner.

Comment: Thank you very much sir..Can I make other two hidden or not?Means if current value of radio button is BCA,then check box 3 and 4 should hide?Is this possible?

Comment: yes sir. give a close look at my JS n try to understand how is it working. cause you might have so many radio buttons and checkboxes. If you understand the code, you can easily customize it. If you face problem , tell me

Comment: Sir I had customized JS Code like


    if(value=='BCA')
    {
  document.getElementById("stat").visibility=hidden;
    }
    else if(value=='B.Com')
    {
        document.getElementById("stat").style.visibility=visible;

    }
But it not hiding check box.Will you help me out little more please? :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jquery aswell, you might want to look for the radiobutton change event and than load the correct checkboxes via Ajax

```
$(function(){
    $('.radioBut').change(function(){
       $('#checkboxes').load('generateCheckboxes.php',{'studentsClass' : $(this).val()});
    });
});
```

Where all Radiobuttons shall have a 'radioBut' class and there should be a target div with id='checkBoxes'

Your php script should echo the checkboxes depending on the radiobuttons value.

Hope this helps